# Printable tab button

Tags: html, css, printing, tabs, user-controls

I'm currently stuck with some HTML code. On my website, I currently have 5 existing tabs but I wanted to make one clickable that redirects the user to a printable page that pops open the print menu specific to their browsing. I think I may be missing something in my HTML code. Underneath you can find a simplified version I extracted from one of my tabs:

```
<div class="tab-item">
 <a class="tab-label text-center"><i class="icon-1-map"></i> Ligging</a>
 <div class="tab-content">
  <iframe src="<!--GOOGLE MAPS LINK-->" style="width:100%; height:400px; frameborder:0; border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>  
</div>
```

I wanted to implement something like this

```
<div class="tab-item">
 <a href="../../print/k420-torhoutsesteenweg306.html">
  <i class="icon-1-print"></i> Print deze pagina
 </a>
</div>
```

The problem is, sometimes the tab doesn't even show up and if I change my code to the one underneath, it doesn't bring me to the linked page.

```
<div class="tab-item">
 <a class="tab-label text-center" href="../../print/k420-torhoutsesteenweg306.html">
  <i class="icon-1-print"></i> Print deze pagina
 </a>
</div>
```

Can anybody help me?

If you'd like to see the full sourcecode, please click [here](http://covicovastgoed.be/verkoop/appartementen/k420-torhoutsesteenweg306.php)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

1) To just open the print dialogue of the page upon loading, simply add this at the bottom of your HTML's `<body>` : `<script>window.print()</script>`

2) As for your disappearing code, please provide more information and/or link your CSS. Also, why are you using `<i>` on its own like that? `<i>` is to display text in *italics*

The information you provide is not enough to correct any issues.

Comment: Hi mark,
Thanks for your reply. I'm trying to implement the button on the following page, where my css is linked if you view the source code: http://covicovastgoed.be/verkoop/appartementen/k420-torhoutsesteenweg306.php
As for the <i>, I used it to mark buttons as it seems to make it easier for me to note where they should or will be. If you have any recommendations, I'd be happy to take any advice you can offer. *Edit: the tab-item class is found in "components.css"